# Perl script not found when on a shared mounted hard drive located on a Windows computer

Tags: linux, perl, path, mount

I'm working on a Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca 64 bits.

I have a simple Perl script named test.pl :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Hello\n" ;
```

Permissions are `-rwxr-xr-x`

My PATH variable is : `/mnt/USERS/user1/:/home/myLogin/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

When this script is in my user bin directory /home/myLogin/bin, I can launch it outside the bin directory by a simple :

```
test.pl
```

The command :

```
which test.pl
```

return

```
/home/myLogin/bin/test.pl
```

That seems ok.

On my Linux I mount a shared windows hard drive located somewhere on my local network.
If I move this script to the Windows mounted hard drive on /mnt/USERS/user1/ I can't run it anymore even if the /mnt/USERS/user1/ is in the $PATH variable.
The system answers "command not found".
If I go to this directory with a cd command, I can't launch the script by a simple :

```
test.pl
```

the error is "command not found".

If I try :

```
./test.pl
```

the error is now "Permission denied"

If I try :

```
perl test.pl
```

it works perfectly...
What's wrong ???
Thanx

Comment: Ok, I thought that my linux saw this disc just as as linux disc. Is there a way to go around this in order to launch my script without the perl prefix in my command line ?

Comment: @serenesat I'm NOT on Windows...

Comment: Please describe your situation properly. The worth of your question is *by far* to help others with a similar problem, so you should document everything carefully when you ask a question. Please do some debugging of your own, for instance the output of `which test.pl` would help a lot. Fancy comebacks like *"I'm NOT on Windows"* don't help you at all because it's not true. If you would like help then please be well-mannered and informative. I'm voting to close your question because the problem can't be replicated.

Comment: @Borodin Sorry I miss some information. I'm on Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca 64 bits. So I'm really not on Windows. When test.pl is in my user bin directory as I said before, `which test.pl` return /home/myLogin/bin/test.pl. When I move it to the mounted Windows Disc in /mnt/USERS/user1/ `which test.pl` return nothing. Why the problem can't be replicated ? Do you have a windows mounted disc on your Linux ? Thanx for your help.

Comment: I added some information on my first post, hope this will be better (and sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 1):

> the error is "command not found".

When you type a command without an explicit path to it (unlike `./test.pl`) then your shell will search the directories listed in `$PATH`. This does not typically include `./` (the current directory), so it doesn't find the script.

> the error is now "Permission denied"

When you try to execute a script directly (as opposed to executing `perl` and passing it the location of the script as an argument, the file permissions must allow execution.

Windows file permissions are not like UNIX file permissions and a Windows formatted disk mounted on UNIX-like systems will typically have hard coded (in the mount command) file permissions. These do not include execution permission for the file you want to execute.

Comment: The mounted disc path is set in my $PATH

Comment: @user6579342 — Possibly the search is limited to executable files then. You still have the file permissions issue.

Comment: my $PATH is :  /mnt/USERS/user1/:/home/myLogin/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: the permissions looks good : -rwxr-xr-x 1 myLogin myLogin 34 juil. 12 14:25 test.pl

Comment: "When you type a command without an explicit path to it (as in ./test.pl) then your shell will search the directories listed in $PATH" It sounds like you're saying `./test.pl` isn't an explicit path and that running `./test.pl` searches `$PATH`. I had to read this about five times before I realized what you actually meant; maybe you could change to wording to clarify?